# Display different image on various devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Joomla 3.3.4 FYI.

I have an image on the front page (http://www.ckdev.info/cdp) that's a call to action to complete a form for a free estimate. It's great in desktop or tablet (landscape) as the form appears to the right.

However, when viewed on other devices or orientations, the viewport is too small to have the sidebar showing on the right and it drops to the bottom. So the "right arrow" image doesn't make logical sense.

What I want to do is a bit of an "if-else" solution. If screen width is xx px or greater show "right-arrow.jpg", else "down-arrow.jpg". I will attach a anchor to the form so that clicking/touching down-arrow.jpg when displayed will scroll down to the form.

I'm afraid I'm no coder so, while I have no doubt this can be done, I have no clue how! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with css media-queries.

Try this: (change 900px and 899px to your desired values)

```
@media(min-width: 900px) {
    #img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background: url('http://www.ckdev.info/cdp/images/estimate.png');
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 899px) {
    #img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: url('http://www.ckdev.info/cdp/images/estimate.png');/*change image url*/
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;        
    }
}
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsjj37cn/1/) (resize result window width to more than 900px)

I've just made your image different size on different media queries, but instead change your background url to your desired image.

Comment: This looks pretty simple - thanks. Thanks to all who replied SO QUICKLY too - awesome! So this would go in my CSS file right? Then, if my image is inside <p>...</p> I use <p class="img;">? Or is it a style?

Comment: Yeah, put it in your CSS. you can use it like <p class="img"> (no semi-colon) but then .img{} insetad of #img{}

Comment: This is definitely the way to go for a single image swap.  I mentioned the js version as I do media swaps for most images on my site using a custom data-src attr. If you dont have to worry about dynamic sources or client added content than css is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again. This is my first post on Stack Overflow (though I trolled its pages before) - I'm blown away with the speedy help!

Comment: One final thing. Can I assign a link to the 2nd image (I would like them to scroll down to an anchor if possible)?

Comment: Yep just like that but ONLY for the 2nd image, not for the image that shows on desktop view. I was hoping it could be added to the CSS for just that 1 image.

Comment: @user1624044 if you expand the window to more than 900px you'll see that the link is applied to smäller image only.

Comment: My apologies caeth <embarrassed grin!> Thank you so much - this is genius (to me!!!)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a CSS media query to change the displayed image.

For a smartphone like the iphone in portait it would be something like that:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

{ /* STYLES GO HERE */}

For more details take a look at:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

[cssmediaqueries](http://www.cssmediaqueries.com)

Comment: Beware of those media queries in IE, it doesnt always play nice with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen using jQuery without anything extra as long as you don't mind some odities in the width of the window that come from the scrollbar.  Ill get back to the scrollbar in a sec.  To test the width you can use `jQuery(window).width()`.  This will return the width of the window in pixels.  Exactly what you are looking for.  An example snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery(window).width() > 1000){
    jQuery(<select img here>).attr('src', '/path/to/new/image.jpg');
  }
});
```

I notice that you dont have a class or id on the image you mentioned.  I would suggest adding an id to make it easier to select.  For example, `<img src="/cdp/images/estimate.png" alt="Get a free interior or exterior painting estimate" id="estimate-with-arrow">`.  If you make this change you can swap out `<select img here>` for `'img#estimate-with-arrow'` (this will select an the image with id estimate-with-arrow).  And voila, image swap.

I will note three things.
First, that this will only work on initial page load.  If a user loads the page at full desktop width then shrinks it down, the image will not change when it passes the break point.  You need to bind to the resize to get this to work:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  <code here>
});
```

Second, I set up this particular code to swap out the image for any screen *over* 1000 px.  This means you will only ever load one image for smaller devices, saving bandwidth.  This is preferred, ad mobile plans are more finicky.

And third, the scrollbar.  Testing the window width using jQuery will not match the same break point as css.  I use modernizr to get around this.  This is a bit more advanced though.